# Laravel 5 - AJAX image upload with CSRF protection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a form set up to upload an image. I was previously using DropZone.js which worked fine and sent the CSRF token along with the ajax call. Everything server side is fine, but when trying to do this without DropZone I am getting token mismatch errors.

This is my AJAX call:

```
    $(document).on('submit', ".hidden-image-upload", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/project/uploadImage',
        data:{
            data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
        },
        dataType:'json',
        async:false,
        type:'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/project/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hidden-image-upload">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="5lgtt8AgbeF3lprptj8HNXVPceRhoJbqBeErBI1k">
    <input class="cover-image-upload-button" name="file" type="file">
</form>
```

How do I go about sorting out my AJAX call / Laravel to work together?

Comment: Where's your CSRF token?

Comment: Try my answer. If it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send the token in headers using $.ajax.

```
$(document).on('submit', ".hidden-image-upload", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/project/uploadImage',
        data:{
            data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
        },
        headers: {
           'X-CSRF-Token': $('form.hidden-image-upload [name="_token"]').val()
        }
        dataType:'json',
        async:false,
        type:'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
});
```

In the worst case, disable CSRF check in that route, just add the route in the array $except inside app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

Comment: When csrf protection is disabled for a route that is required to be accessed by only authenticated users, your application becomes prone to session-hijacks by hackers and you put your site and users in danger. Disabling csrf protection for file uploads should NEVER be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You must also pass your CSRF Token along with your FormData:

```
$(document).on('submit', ".hidden-image-upload", function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var data = new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]);
    data.append('_token', $('input[name="token"]').val());

$.ajax({
    url:'/project/uploadImage',
    data:{
        data: data,
    },
    dataType:'json',
    async:false,
    type:'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

});

Comment: Please do not do this. Rather, follow the guidelines set out in the documentation and set the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header.